# Cannot find name module in Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular-cli for running my typescript powered angular2 app. I have an `AppComponent` defined like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServersListComponent } from './servers-list/servers-list.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    directives: []
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

angular-cli can't compile this file, because it complains with an error mentioned in topic of this question in the line `moduleId: module.id`.

My `tsconfig.json` file is defined as below:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "mapRoot": "",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "../dist/",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "inlineSources": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: you don't need `moduleId: module.id` when using angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

To be able `module.id`, your project must be a commonjs module, i.e. the `module` attribute set to `commonjs` in the tsconfig.json file. Is it the case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs", // <-----
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. As you can see I have `module: commonjs` in there.

Answer (score 1):

A possible work-around could be to add a app.d.ts file like this

https://github.com/johnpapa/pbp-a2-ward/blob/010523471e70677ba2493eb615c8e6316e3d4ee8/app/app.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

### Update mid 2017

Since angular migrated to using [webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) there is no longer a need to declare `moduleId` as webpack plugins auto handle (add it) `module.id` in the final bundle.

As of [13.03.2017](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html#!#all-mention-of-moduleid-removed-component-relative-paths-cookbook-deleted-2017-03-13-) Angular has removed all references to `moduleId` as it is now deprecated due to the inclusion of webpack.

> We added a new SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to our recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute paths" for you.
>
> We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. **You no longer need to write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), nor should you.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today when creating a first component in a feature folder using the angular-cli. As Maxime said, you can do this without a module id. But you have to use a relative path for your template and your styles, like inside the initially generated app.component:

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
```